# File System Watcher only checks complete files

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io

I'm setting up a system which monitors a directory for images and then processes them.

From time to time PDFs may be dropped into the watched directory, in this case I convert them to an image and continue as normal.

However once the image has been processed it moves it into a complete folder but if the PDF to image conversion isn't complete then my code throws an IO Exception because it can't move a file which is being used by another process.

Is it possible when specifying the notify filters to only process "complete" files. By complete I mean it has finished copying, moving, or being created.

I am guessing that this conflict occurs because the worker than handles the files is running on different threads.

```
public void Start()
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.fileDirectory))
  {
    throw new Exception("No file directory specified.");
  }

  // watch for any type of file activity
  const NotifyFilters Filters = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;

  // set up the watcher based on the app.config file
  var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher() { Path = this.fileDirectory, NotifyFilter = Filters, EnableRaisingEvents = true };

  // event handler for new files
  watcher.Created += this.NewFileCreated;

  // file system watcher doesn't "see" current files, manually get these
  this.ProcessExistingFiles();
}

private void NewFileCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  Task.Run(() => this.ProcessFile(e.FullPath));
}

private void ProcessExistingFiles()
{
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(this.fileDirectory);
  Parallel.ForEach(files, this.ProcessFile);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you write the image files directly into the "Completed" directory and delete them if the processing fails?

Comment: IME, moving, (not copying), a closed file is treated as an 'atomic' operation by the file system.  I have not tried this stuff in C#, but when using the folder notification API's, (which I assume FileSystemWatcher uses), from Delphi, I have no problem with immediately opening etc. a file that has been moved.

Comment: I put them into another folder after conversion and then processed them straight away. Simple solution to what could have been a complex problem. If you put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @CodeCaster- And what does he do in case the process crashes? There will be files in the completed directory that will never be processed (unless he has an independent marking algorithm).

Comment: @Vitaliy that is a great point, never even thought of that. I guess I can put the converted files into a "Converted" folder and then put another line in the ProcessExistingFiles function to check that folder at start up.

Comment: You could. Please see my answer for another option. Another important thing I think you should pay attention to is the prepossessing stage you make on the existing files. What worries me is the Parallel.ForEach: note that if the majority of the processing is not CPU bound, you may have a degradation in performance, since you are trying to read more than one file simultaneously from disk. Again, this is not ceratain and depends on the nature of the computation. Just be aware of it.

Comment: @Vitality the process crashing is a problem in both cases (since otherwise the file will be incomplete in the "Processing" directory), so that is irrelevant. Put a try-catch block around the processing code to catch errors and remove the file if an error occurred.

Comment: The problem of crashes, and so incompletely processed files, can usually by got around by renaming the file extn appropriately and deleting any '*.tmp' files on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have files two types of files that arrive to a monitored directory: images and pdf's. If a pdf arrives, you must first convert it to an image. I am not sure what is the reason for the exception you describe- is the conversion and the processing (with moving in the end) done simultaneously?

If not- you are looking in the wrong place. It may be that the process that put the file there in the first place is still holding a handle to it.

If the answer is yes, then I have two suggestions:

1. Put the pdf files into a different folder. The conversion process will listen to this folder and will make the move as soon as the images are extracted. This way, you do not need to change anything in the current algorithm, just add another isolation level.
2. Alternatively, you can set a filter on the FSW to monitor only image files (filter file extension) this way, when a pdf is put to the directory, it does not go straight away to processing, it first gets converted to an image. At the end of the conversion, the monitored directory suddenly "receives" another another image! And the process continues as normal. This is essentially another way to receive isolation between the images and the pdfs.

Comment: Point 2 is not true, the FileSystemWatcher will be fired as soon as the file is created while it may still be locked for writing from the PDF to image conversion script. Converting should be done in a different directory, then a move should take place.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you can try to lock files for writing, if this operation fails - file not completed - wait some time (for next changes or 1 second, for example).